# prove that if $C$ and $C'$ are any two $k-cycle$ in $G$, then $C$ and $C'$ have at lease 2 vertices in common.

Tags: graph-theory

Let $k$ be the maximum length of a cycle in a non-separable graph $G$

a) prove that if $C$ and $C'$ are any two $k-cycle$ in $G$, then $C$ and $C'$ have at least 2 vertices in common.

b) Show that the result in a) cannot be improved.

Here is what I got so far.

a) Since $C$ and $C'$ are cycle, $k \geq 3$. Let $U,V$ be subset of  vertices in $C$ and $C'$ respectively such that $|U|=|V|=2$. Since $G$ is non-separable, there are 2 disjoint path connecting vertices of $U$ and vertices of $V$. Now I'm stuck.

Comment: I have not worked out a rigorous proof yet, but the idea should be to construct a larger cycle if the two cycles have at most one common vertex. If they are disjoint, two paths between the cycles should exist and if they have one common vertex, one path between the cycles should exist and with the common vertex, it should be possible to construct a larger cycle again.

Comment: The complete bipartite graph $\large K_{2,4}$ is an example to approve claim b)

Comment: can you explain it a little further please? I'm not sure I understand how construct the larger cycle will show that $C$ and $C'$ have 2 vertices in common. If something contain those 2 vertices, it should be the bigger cycle, not $C$ and $C'$, right?

Comment: The idea was to construct a cycle larger than $C$ and $C'$ to disprove that the cycles can have less than $2$ common vertices. For this I wanted to take the paths in the cycles (which can be chosen with length $\ge \frac{k}{2}$) plus the path(s) between the vertices of the cycles.

Comment: But I am not sure if this construction works in every graph.